# Scrapy Authentication to some site

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I need my parser to log in to the site https://kmt5.com.ua/access-denied

```
class KMTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'kmt'
start_urls = ['https://kmt5.com.ua/kompyuternaya-periferiya/']
login_url = 'https://kmt5.com.ua/login'

def parse(self, response):
    yield response.follow(response.css('div[data-href="https://kmt5.com.ua/login/"]::attr(data-href)').get(),
                          self.login)

def login(self, response):
    form = response.css('div.remodal.modal-login form[action="/login/"]')

    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={
            'email': 'email',
            'password': 'password'
        },
        formcss='div.remodal.modal-login form[action="/login/"]',
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self):
    pass
```

I tested many options, here is one of them, but I do not have much experience in developing such parsers, I suspect that there is some small error, please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This site to which you are trying to log in is a JavaScript-based site. Therefore, you cannot log in with Scrapy because Scrapy only allows static websites. If you want to log in to this type of website, which uses JavaScript, you can use Selenium as an alternative. Selenium is known for browser automation.

Here is the official Selenium documentation [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)

Comment: It's a simple web form submitted via POST, no JS support is needed.

Comment: Have you tried it with scrapy? Because when i tried it needed js to render login page.

Comment: You don't need to render a page to send a correct POST request.